# Save Markdown as interactive HTML

Tags: html, r, shiny, markdown

Is it possible to convert this interactive markdown report into an html and save it to as specific folder (the goal is to to keep this report alive outside R)? If yes, how?

````
---
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---    

```{r echo=FALSE}
N<-c('A','B','C'); V<-c(60,50,80); mydf<-data.frame(N,V)
selectInput("sel","Select:",choices = as.character(mydf$N))
renderText({
     paste("The result is:",mydf[mydf$N==input$sel,2])
})
```
````

Thanks&kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the settings in Rstudio (next to `run document`), choose `Preview in Viewer Panel`.  This will use your browser instead of the built-in browser of Rstudio.

Then you will see that the html file is saved on your hard disk:

```
processing file: testing_interactive.Rmd

"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS "C:/Users/TB/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKYheKO/testing_interactive.utf8.md" --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc83c74213d5c.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Rlibs\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable "theme:bootstrap" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --id-prefix section- 
output file: C:/Users/TB/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKYheKO/testing_interactive.knit.md


Output created: C:/Users/TB/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKYheKO/file83c15d05b9c.html
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems I got it wrong from the start. What I did was (in R Studio):

1. File > New File > R Markdown .. // 2. Presentation & HTML (Slidy) // 3. OK // 4. copy the code from above // 5. Knit HTML > Knit to HTML (Slidy) // 6. (Clicking on the cogwheel symbol) only gives "Output Options .."

Comment: If I use ioslides, the available options are View Pane, View in Window, Output Options ..

Comment: Yes exactly. Even if you are on ioslides i.e. your front matter would have `output: ioslides_presentation` (the default), by selecting `View Pane` will show you the html file path in the same way as above.

Comment: I can open the html file, but my shiny leaflet and output plot are missing.